# Getting a reference to the UIApplication delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton, delegates, uiapplication

I'm writing my first iPhone application and I'm having trouble switching views.  I have 2 views and a reference to each in the `AppDelegate` (an instance of `UIApplicationDelegate`).  I create instances of both in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and immediately show the first view.  This works fine.

The problem is the reference to the other view is in the **AppDelegate** and I can't figure out how to get a reference to it so I can switch to the other view.  Is there a way to get a reference to the main `UIApplication` or `UIApplicationDelegate` objects?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Yes, UIApplication is a singleton, and uses the normal singleton pattern for Objective-C:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication];
```

You can get your delegate class directly from it:

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: it may be obvious but worth noting that MyApplicationDelegate is the name of the class that conforms to the protocol **UIApplicationDelegate**, in many cases **AppDelegate**

Comment: I am trying this but getting errors.
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) - Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead.

Answer (score 19):

Use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```