# Refreshing a view controller class inside a notification centre

Tags: iphone, ios

i am using notification centre with tabbar controller and navigation controller .In first page i am not using both tabbar and navigation bar.In home page my global value null.but after went through tabbar classes the value wil be changed.but it did not happend in homepage which means not refreshing the global value in that page(using notification centre).is there any way to refresh that particular home page?

Comment: What does your code look like where you are listening for a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the homepage is part of the navigation hierarchy you could use methods from the navigation controller to get a reference to it. If that's not the case you could also use the App Delegate by keeping a reference to the home page and then accessing it like this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184146/getting-a-reference-to-the-uiapplication-delegate) suggests